# How to override PreBid.js adserverTargeting bidderSettings

Tags: javascript, google-dfp, prebid.js

I am trying to use a different bidder setting key name in my prebid solution.

I have included the 6 required keys as noted in the documentation. To rename a key do i simply change the key name: 'hb_pb' to key: 'zm_hb_pb' like I did in the code example I have provided? And then let my ad ops team know? Or is there something else I have to do? This would be a global change for all bidders.

```
pbjs.bidderSettings = {
  standard: {

    adserverTargeting: [
      ...
      {
        key: 'zm_hb_pb',
        val: function(bidResponse) {
          return bidResponse.pbMg;
        }
      },
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enter each config setting for each ad exchange. I can't see that prebid allow for a global setting, but you can probably automate it yourself.

```
const adserverTargeting = [{
   key:"your_key"
   ..
}]
pbjs.bidderSettings = { 
  appnexus: {
    adserverTargeting: adserverTargeting
    ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn out my code was working fine as described above.
I needed to modify return bidResponse.pbMg;